# Set volume with Chromecast when Android app is in the background

Tags: android, chromecast

I'm developing an app for Android that streams content to a Chromecast device. 
I did not find the documentation about the way to change the volume of the remote media player when the app is in the background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the method `setUpRemoteControl()` in `VideoCastManager` class, in CCL; it is mostly done there.

Answer (score 2):

It was enough to call:

mediaRouter.addRemoteControlClient(mRemoteControlClient);

where:

mMediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance(context);

Answer (score 1):

Per the [CastCompanionLibrary detailed documentation](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android/raw/master/CastCompanionLibrary.pdf):

> CCL can provide default lock screen controllers based on the RemoteControlClient. If desired, 
>   this feature needs to be enabled at the initialization time of the VideoCastManager. When this 
>   feature is enabled, a Play/Pause button will be shown on Android devices running Jelly Bean or 
>   above. On KitKat devices, the layout of the lock screen controllers is different and uses a 
>   full-screen album art while on Jelly Bean it is a small version of the album art.
>
> In addition, when this feature is enabled, CCL provides the ability for users to control the Cast 
>   device’s system’s volume even if the application is in the background. On KitKat devices, it provides that capability even if the screen is off

For the CastVideos-android sample, they do that in [CastApplication](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android/blob/master/src/com/google/sample/cast/refplayer/CastApplication.java) immediately after intialization of `VideoCastManager`:

```
mCastMgr.enableFeatures(
    VideoCastManager.FEATURE_NOTIFICATION |
    VideoCastManager.FEATURE_LOCKSCREEN |
    VideoCastManager.FEATURE_DEBUGGING);
```