# Volume slider while casting

Tags: android, chromecast

I need to show the volume slider while casting an audio content to a Chromecast remote.

If I put the app to the background the slider is shown (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330912/set-volume-with-chromecast-when-android-app-is-in-the-background/24361399#24361399)).

The problem is that the framework does not show the slider when the app is not in the background.I guess it is because an application can decide to do something else.

I have tried to call

```
mAudioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_SAME, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

with no success: the slider that is shown does not have the Chromecast icon and does not report the current volume on the remote. In other words the slider is related with the local audio volume.

is there a way to ask the framework to keep showing the slider even when the app is in the foreground?

**Edited**
Actually the behaviour even with the VideoCast app is a bit inconsistent. On some phones it is enough to bring the app in the background and make the framework showing the volume slider. After that it will keep showing it even when the app is in the foreground. On other phones this does not work or it is not necessary because the slider is shown correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bit of improvement that can be made; when media is playing back (i.e. if it is not on pause), you can achieve what you want. To see how, you need to override `onKeyDown`; take a look at the CastVideos-android sample, in class `VideoBrowserActivity` and try that to see if it does what you'd like or not.

Comment: I have already done that. The problem is showing the slider. I would prefer not to make my own once

Comment: Try CastVideos-android; I believe it shows the volume slider in the application when casting and media is playing; the return value of the onKeyDown is important.

Comment: I tried CastVideos-android. It does not show the slider

Comment: I just tried that again and it does show the slider.

Comment: when on the foreground?

Comment: I do not see the chromecast volume slider on some phones but I can see it on others

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to show the Chromecast control instead of the generic music control, you need to call:

```
mAudioManager.adjustSuggestedStreamVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_SAME,
            AudioManager.USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```